# Creating a PDF with variable column widths and row blocks

Tags: tables, tabulary, makecell

I'm trying to create a script that will take in data with variable lengths and which needs to be put in a PDF report. The number of columns are fixed, but the content needs to be shifted. As it's a script I won't be able to manually check if the data is still bounded by the cells. They just need to fit in the table and take up a majority of the page.

Other answers suggested to use tabulary for variable width columns, so I tried the following.

```
%\usepackage{tabulary}
%\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{|C|C|C|c|c|c|}\hline\centering
\rowcolor{lightgray}Product Name & Configuration & Quantity & Unit Price & Price with tax & Total \\\hline\hline

573-MCJJ & Dyu njslw qonycxekcins ouneukdl U3821DWasds gf baba& 1 & 75934 & 97195.52 & 97195.52  \\\hline
573-MCJJ & Dyu njslw qonycxekcins ouneukdl U3821DWasds gf baba& 1 & 75934 & 97195.52 & 97195.52  \\\hline
573-MCJJ & Dyu njslw qonycxekcins ouneukdl U3821DWasds gf baba& 1 & 75934 & 97195.52 & 97195.52  \\\hline
573-MCJJ & Dyu njslw qonycxekcins ouneukdl U3821DWasds gf baba& 1 & 75934 & 97195.52 & 97195.52  \\\hline
573-MCJJ & Dyu njslw qonycxekcins ouneukdl U3821DWasds gf baba& 1 & 75934 & 97195.52 & 97195.52  \\\hline\hline
&&&&&continued...\\\hline

%\rowcolor{lightgray}&&&&& \\\hline

\end{tabulary}
\end{center}
\pagebreak
```

This gave a pretty good layout.

[image]

I want the rows to break after every 5 rows so it's easier to count. On a full page I could fit about 5 of them. But if the numbers get bigger they move out of the the cell bounds. No way to fix that. As it's not a table, I couldn't center the numbers as well.

So I tried another way, using normal table but one which resizes.

```
%\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{table}
    \makegapedcells
    \centering
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%resizing the whole table
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline 
    \rowcolor{gray}Product Name & Configuration & Quantity & Unit Price & Price with GST & Total \\\hline\hline

210BEGN & Dyu njslw qonycxekcins o & 1 & 75934 & 97195.52 & 97195.52  \\\hline210BEGN & Dyu njslw qonycxekcins o & 1 & 75934 & 97195.52 & 97195.52  \\\hline 210BEGN & Dyu njslw qonycxekcins o & 1 & 75934 & 97195.52 & 97195.52  \\\hline 210BEGN & Dyu njslw qonycxekcins o & 1 & 75934 & 97195.52 & 97195.52  \\\hline 210BEGN & Dyu njslw qonycxekcins o & 1 & 75934 & 97195.52 & 97195.52  \\\hline 210BEGN & Dyu njslw qonycxekcins o & 1 & 75934 & 97195.52 & 97195.52  \\\hline\hline
%&&&&&continued...\\\hline

573-MCJJ & \makecell{Dyu njslw qonycxekcins \\ofdjlsj U3821DWasds gf baba}& 1 & 75934 & 97195.52 & 97195.52  \\\hline

\end{tabular}
   }

\end{table}
```

This resizes, but the multiline cells give a black row for some reason, along with no gray row color for the title.

[image]

Any better ways to go about this?

Comment: "But if the numbers get bigger they move out of the cell bounds."   Post a compilable MWE showing this case. A priori this should not happen,  because  columns 1, 2 and 3 should be tightened accordingly. If this can leave the first  columns with  ridiculous widths, reduce the font size using `\small`,  or `\footnotosize`, or etc. but do **not** resize the tables in a case basis, so each one will have a different font size and line widths (not ugly, but the following ...).

Comment: The thing is I am not sure where to use those sizes as it will be in a script. I could just check if the number is greater than a certain number of digits then apply the \small or \footnote, this messes up a bit of the the look with different.

Comment: You can't build a good tabular layout only on the vage idea "I have five columns". You need at first to have a better idea about your contraints and the data. E.g. if the PDF has to be A4 portrait or can get larger, which font size are acceptable (e.g. if it gets printed tiny is not a good idea), which columns allow line breaks, the range of your data.